# apache storm spout not emitting tuples

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-storm

I have setup a test enviroment on a aws cluster using three machines and [this](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-multi-node-storm-cluster/#submitting-the-topology-to-the-cluster) guide.

I tested my code in local mode and using wirbelsturm to create a local vagrant cluster, both of which works gives desired results.

When i now submit my code to the webserver my spouts and all of my bolts are silent. My spout reads from a csv, which I have copied to the nimbus and my supervisor. The storm UI shows me the topology as active and displays all bolts and my spout, the counters are not visible though. The supervisor has no used workers. The firewall is configured to let nimbus and supervisor accept the ports 6700-6703 from supervisor and nimbus. Does the zookeeper talk on those ports?

I can't seem to find my output logs on my machines either. I find ui and nimbus logs in /usr/local/storm/logs of nimbus and slave but other than that i do not seem to get an error or even logs for spouts/bolts. The vagrant machines show a worker-xxxx.log, but my aws servers do not.

Is that because my code crashes on some error or because i did a config wrong?

Update: I verified my topology with the storm-starter example, those do not seem to work either. I used mvn package to build an uberjar.

Update2:

I included the log from my supervisor, doesnt show any errors but maybe theres something in there...

```
 2015-12-08 13:42:55.168 b.s.u.Utils [INFO] Using defaults.yaml from resources
2015-12-08 13:42:55.297 b.s.u.Utils [INFO] Using storm.yaml from resources
2015-12-08 13:42:57.434 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
2015-12-08 13:42:57.435 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:host.name=ip-172-31-26-239.us-west-2.compute.internal
2015-12-08 13:42:57.435 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_91
2015-12-08 13:42:57.435 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2015-12-08 13:42:57.435 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/jre
2015-12-08 13:42:57.435 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:java.class.path=/usr/local/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/clojure-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/log4j-core-2.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-sto$
2015-12-08 13:42:57.435 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib
2015-12-08 13:42:57.435 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2015-12-08 13:42:57.435 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2015-12-08 13:42:57.436 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:os.name=Linux
2015-12-08 13:42:57.436 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2015-12-08 13:42:57.436 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64
2015-12-08 13:42:57.436 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:user.name=storm
2015-12-08 13:42:57.436 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:user.home=/app/home/storm
2015-12-08 13:42:57.436 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:user.dir=/
2015-12-08 13:42:57.459 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
2015-12-08 13:42:57.459 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:host.name=ip-172-31-26-239.us-west-2.compute.internal
2015-12-08 13:42:57.459 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:java.version=1.7.0_91
2015-12-08 13:42:57.459 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2015-12-08 13:42:57.459 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/jre
2015-12-08 13:42:57.460 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:java.class.path=/usr/local/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/clojure-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/log4j-core-2.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/ap$
2015-12-08 13:42:57.460 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib
2015-12-08 13:42:57.460 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2015-12-08 13:42:57.460 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2015-12-08 13:42:57.460 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:os.name=Linux
2015-12-08 13:42:57.460 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:os.arch=amd64
2015-12-08 13:42:57.460 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:os.version=2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64
2015-12-08 13:42:57.460 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:user.name=storm
2015-12-08 13:42:57.460 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:user.home=/app/home/storm
2015-12-08 13:42:57.460 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:user.dir=/
2015-12-08 13:42:57.774 b.s.u.Utils [INFO] Using defaults.yaml from resources
2015-12-08 13:42:57.803 b.s.u.Utils [INFO] Using storm.yaml from resources
2015-12-08 13:42:57.939 b.s.d.supervisor [INFO] Starting Supervisor with conf {"topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs" 60, "nimbus.childopts" "-Xmx1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true", "ui.filter.params" nil, "storm.cluster.mode" "distributed", "storm.messaging.net$
2015-12-08 13:42:57.963 b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry [INFO] The baseSleepTimeMs [1000] the maxSleepTimeMs [30000] the maxRetries [5]
2015-12-08 13:42:58.063 o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl [INFO] Starting
2015-12-08 13:42:58.066 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Initiating client connection, connectString=zkserver1:2181 sessionTimeout=20000 watcher=org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@502016b8
2015-12-08 13:42:58.081 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection to server zkServer1/xx.xx.xx.xx:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-12-08 13:42:58.089 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Socket connection established to zkServer1/xx.xx.xx.xx:2181, initiating session
2015-12-08 13:42:58.094 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Session establishment complete on server zkServer1/xx.xx.xx.xx:2181, sessionid = 0x15182c7ba25000d, negotiated timeout = 20000
2015-12-08 13:42:58.096 o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager [INFO] State change: CONNECTED
2015-12-08 13:42:58.097 b.s.zookeeper [INFO] Zookeeper state update: :connected:none
2015-12-08 13:42:59.109 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] EventThread shut down
2015-12-08 13:42:59.110 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Session: 0x15182c7ba25000d closed
2015-12-08 13:42:59.111 b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry [INFO] The baseSleepTimeMs [1000] the maxSleepTimeMs [30000] the maxRetries [5]
2015-12-08 13:42:59.116 o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl [INFO] Starting
2015-12-08 13:42:59.116 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Initiating client connection, connectString=zkserver1:2181/storm sessionTimeout=20000 watcher=org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@5edfa0aa
2015-12-08 13:42:59.121 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection to server zkServer1/xx.xx.xx.xx:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-12-08 13:42:59.122 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Socket connection established to zkServer1/xx.xx.xx.xx:2181, initiating session
2015-12-08 13:42:59.124 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Session establishment complete on server zkServer1/xx.xx.xx.xx:2181, sessionid = 0x15182c7ba25000e, negotiated timeout = 20000
2015-12-08 13:42:59.124 o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager [INFO] State change: CONNECTED
2015-12-08 13:42:59.169 b.s.d.supervisor [INFO] Starting supervisor with id cc5e1723-cc06-4bc1-a1bf-192a1d7f5bf6 at host xxxxxxx.us-west-2.compute.internal
2015-12-08 13:43:06.059 b.s.d.supervisor [INFO] Downloading code for storm id production-topology-4-1449599549 from /app/storm/nimbus/stormdist/production-topology-4-1449599549
2015-12-08 13:43:06.075 b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry [INFO] The baseSleepTimeMs [2000] the maxSleepTimeMs [60000] the maxRetries [5]
```

Any ideas?

Update2:

So i did find this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at backtype.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.retryNext(TBackoffConnect.java:59) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:51) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:103) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.<init>(ThriftClient.java:72) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.<init>(NimbusClient.java:74) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:37) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.downloadFromMaster(Utils.java:361) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$fn__7720.invoke(supervisor.clj:581) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:241) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$mk_synchronize_supervisor$this__7638.invoke(supervisor.clj:465) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__7258.invoke(event.clj:40) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_91]
Caused by: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin.connect(SimpleTransportPlugin.java:103) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:48) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
        at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin.connect(SimpleTransportPlugin.java:103) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:48) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        ... 11 more
2015-12-08 14:26:41.028 b.s.util [ERROR] Halting process: ("Error when processing an event")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Error when processing an event")
        at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:336) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__7258.invoke(event.clj:48) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_91]
```

Comment: You say that "The supervisor has no used workers." and that you do not see any worker logs. This sound as if the worker JVM cannot get started by the supervisors. Is there any error in the supervisor logs?

Comment: the supervisor.log doesnt seem to indicate any reasons as why there should be a any failures. Could it be that the supervisor somehow doesnt seem to get the "commands" to start a worker due to false port settings?

Comment: Do i need to open the DRPC ports?

Comment: If there is no error message, I have no idea. Sorry. :/

Comment: added my logs anyway, maybe you can finde something...

Comment: also posted an error i found

Comment: ok so i openend the 6627 to anywhere instead of the supervisor security group, now it uses a work but still doesnt emit any tuples...

Comment: You mean that a worker JVM is started? Do you see the worker log? Any error there? Did you check the worker ports?

Comment: yup ist working now, the aws servers behave not the way I expect them to when using security groups to configure the firewalls

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same guide as you and ran into the same issue.
What solved the problem for me :

Edit the 3 `/etc/hosts` files of your three machines (zookeeper, nimbus and slave1) the same way

- First remove the IPv6 line which starts like `::1`, this is not supported by apache storm.
- In the first line of the file, containing local aliases, place the public hostname of the local machine (the one known by other nodes of the cluster) just after `127.0.0.1`. I suppose this is the alias storm will take into account.
- Finally, as told in the guide list all the other machines and there storm-knowned hostnames

Finally my `/etc/hosts` looks like this (for the nimbus)

```
127.0.0.1 vm-matthias-02 localhost.localdomain localhost
192.168.200.48  vm-matthias-01
192.168.200.49  vm-matthias-02
192.168.200.50  vm-matthias-03
```

Beware to use the same name of the machine when you edit configuration files.